# Why was this link removed in my question?

Tags: support, edits, specific-question

I asked [a question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30761/how-can-a-pirated-blu-ray-be-released-online-before-the-official-blu-ray-release) regarding how a Blu-ray disk can be released online before the official Blu-ray release date on Stacke Exchange site *[Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tour)*. So I used a link for source, but someone removed it. They said, refrain from linking to pirated content on this site. Here I want to raise a question, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759158/python-parsing-html) - the user posted a pirated link, but it is still visible. But when I post a link it was removed; why only me?

Comment: This probably would be better posted on the Movies.SE meta- the answer under your post mentions that your question had a link to a torrent site.

Comment: @SabreTooth the OP is a 1 rep user over there as well and therefore can't participate on the site's Meta just yet.

Comment: @Bart ah yes, I see - however in the comments, this question was asked (twice)

Comment: Did Ganondorf visit you?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this. As said, the OP couldn't take it to the specific site it pertains to, so this site works just fine.

Answer (score 13):

There is no "only for you" here. Your post was seen and appropriately handled. Don't post such links please. It seems that the exact link wasn't even necessary for the premise of your question.

It is unfortunately not always good practice to take other posts as an example of what you can and cannot do on a particular site within the network. Especially not when looking at two completely distinct sites. Maybe the other post was overlooked. Maybe rules were different in the past. There can be a whole range of reasons why another post is still around while yours was changed or removed. But that doesn't justify you posting such content, nor does it imply you should have been treated differently.

In this particular case one could argue that the mention on Stack Overflow is nothing more than a string used in a programming example. It doesn't actually link to anything and on a non-movie-related site one could interpret it as just that; an example string. However, I would personally not mind if the particular string was edited out over there as well, though that would be more involved and I wouldn't want to burn my hands on that.

Comment: Oh, this is why people were flagging that question to be deleted. I was baffled by that. I declined those flags, because I'm not going to delete an entire question because of the sample data potentially being a movie torrent. The point of the question wasn't the torrent, it was the access to that data. Someone else can edit in something more innocuous, but I'm not deleting that post because of a URL in its code.

Comment: You mean that the SO question got a bunch of flags @BradLarson? That seems a bit much. By "if it were removed" I meant the string at most. Not the post itself.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow and Movies Stack Exchange are two different sites, with two different communities. In general, just because something *may be* okay on one site doesn't necessarily mean that it will be okay on another. The rules of Stack Exchange are, for the most part, dictated by the users who participate on the sites. Because of that, rules can vary dramatically between sites. You can't reliably see something as acceptable on one, and assume it will be on another. There are definitely cross-overs, like questions seeking discussions or opinions are outlawed (except on Meta sites) because they really don't fit the Q&A format very well, but the subtleties, like what non-spam links will be allowed, are really up to the moderators and community to decide, and more relevantly, to enforce.

And that even said, nobody is claiming that it is okay in the Stack Overflow version either. I think it is, because it's necessary information to the question, whereas yours was more or less auxiliary, but regardless of that, just because you see something in one question doesn't mean that it'll implicitly be a perfect match for the Stack Exchange format or guidelines.

I think you need to reassess the situation a little. Very rarely--indeed I would probably hazard "never"--are good edits the result of personal feelings. The user who took out that link were acting on your post, on behalf of the site. There's nothing personal to it. You weren't singled out.

You're definitely not wrong to question the edit--it's important to understand why users make decisions, if for no other reason than so that you better understand the guidelines in the future--but it's important to take the edit for what it is. It's not an attack against you or the post, it's just a request that you don't post links to unlawful content, which, to me at least, seems like a fairly reasonable request.